# How are different content types within QR-Codes distinguished?

Tags: qr-code, url-scheme, vcf-vcard

QR-Codes can contain different contents (URLs, vCards, Wifi-Configurations...) - in the specification of QR-Code seems nothing defined regarding content.

How these different content types are distinguished? Only via parsing the first few characters of the content and matching to URL schemes (http:, tel:, fb:)? Or is there another 'magic' value inside the code?

So it seems impossible to encode multiple contents in ONE QR-Code without gambling with reader-app-compatibility... e.g. one URL and some text in ONE code.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: QR Code is just a string, it does not provide any means for content types.

Comment: You can use this: https://github.com/mahendragp/MGPBarcodeScanner

Answer (score 2):

> How these different content types are distinguished? Only via parsing the first few characters of the content and matching to URL schemes (http:, tel:, fb:)?

Yes. A QR Code just contains a string of UTF-8 characters.  It is up to the QR Scanner to interpret the text.

Typically it will look at the first few characters to see if they match a scheme it recognises.

> So it seems impossible to encode multiple contents in ONE QR-Code without gambling with reader-app-compatibility... e.g. one URL and some text in ONE code.

That's right. Typically a single QR code contains a single piece of information.  If you have a code which is `http://example.com/\nVisit Us!` then it is likely that some readers will get confused.

The best thing you can do it create a URL which points to a web page containing the different types of data.  For example, my QR codes point to `http://edent.tel/` the website then has `mailto:`, `http://`, `VCARD`, `tel:` etc.