# How to find content type of qr code in ios in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, qr-code

I am developing an iOS application where I am scanning QRCode and showing result to user. I am scanning QRCode by native libraries provided by *Apple*. I am able to get string/content from QRCode but I am unable to distinguish and parse string/content. I want to get the type of data (distinguish data type) present in QRCode as it may have different types of data, for example `url, text, mcard, email data`. I also want to parse content i.e. getting fields of data, for example in case of email data, I want to get email, cc, subject and body field. This question [How are different content types within QR-Codes distinguished?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33774027/how-are-different-content-types-within-qr-codes-distinguished) did not helped because it does not have accepted answer which can help me.

Comment: Hello, Dudy, welcome to stackOverflow, can you add what you have so far, and can you explain a little more about what you mean with (distinguish and parse string/content)

Comment: Reinier Melian, I have edited question. Please read again.

Comment: You can use this: https://github.com/mahendragp/MGPBarcodeScanner

Comment: github.com/mahendragp/MGPBarcodeScanner is very inefficient, that library is unable to detect qr-code type. I downloaded it and check demo on sample qr-code available on google, but unfortunately while scanning email qr-code, it is unable to detect qr-code type and only shows it type as "Other"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `.stringValue` obtained from a `AVMetadataObject` scan is just that - a "string value." It is up to you to parse the content.

There are a number of predefined data types, such as

- a URL, where the string starts with "https://";
- an email link, e.g. "mailto:somebody@example.com?subject=Mail%20from%20Our%20Site"

There is also a "VCard" spec, which may be formatted with "field" values:

```
BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:3.0
N:Owen;Sean;;;
FN:Sean Owen
TITLE:Software Engineer
EMAIL;TYPE=INTERNET;TYPE=WORK;TYPE=PREF:srowen@google.com
URL;TYPE=Homepage:https://example.com
END:VCARD
```

for example.

So, you check the start of the string. If it begins with "https://" your app might launch Safari. If it begins with "mailto:" you could launch the mail app. If it begins with "BEGIN:VCARD" then you'd parse the predefined fields and use the data in your app.

There is a good summary of predefined types here (although, it may be a bit out-of-date): https://github.com/zxing/zxing/wiki/Barcode-Contents

Of course, you can create your own types for your own purposes. For example, you can create a QR-Code that contains:

```
myTypeA:Robert
```

or:

```
myTypeB:Driver
```

then your app would get the string, take one action if it begins with `myTypeA:` and a different action if it begins with `myTypeB:`.